# Possible to 'layer' Android applications?

Tags: java, android

I know this in general is beyond the scope of SO, but I am looking for some basic yes/no info to see if it is even feasible to proceed...  I am thinking about building and Android 'note-taking/annotation' app that runs 'over' other installed Android apps, such as the web browser for example.

Essentially, while the user is browsing, my app would be running in the bg as a service, and then they could activate it which would then essentially intercept user inputs and translate those on a transparent canvas over the web browser into lines, shapes, etc.  The user could then take a screen-cap of their marking with the underlying web page, which would be stored to the sd card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very good idea and a great question, but sadly, I do not believe it is possible.

The way Android is designed only one `Activity` can have focus at a time, while a `Service` could run in the background, the user would not be able to interact with it. The user can only interact with the currently active `Activity`.

Again, love the idea, but it is sadly not supported.

Comment: I believe this answer is correct but you may be able to get a little clever with shortcuts so a certain key combo (Search-N) for example might switch to your app and allow note taking. The user could then "Back" to the previous app. I don't believe you'd be able to determine what that app was though - The joys of a sandboxed environment :)

Comment: How would you set up the key combo though?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve this with the [WindowManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.html) service. You can then use that to call `addView()` with a view of type [`TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT), or possibly `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` (but see the notes in the documentation about taking input focus).

I haven't tried it myself, but I've seen several apps (often dictionary apps that translate whatever words you tap on) that do overlays, and they always seem to require the [`SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) permission.